# Can't integrate a function

Tags: matlab

I defined a function

```
temp = [2;1.5; 0.75; 1.5; 3.75; 0.75; 1.25; .075; 2.0; 1.0; 1.0]; 
A1 = @(x) temp(floor(x*10)+1);
```

it's a single input single output function. I want to integrate A1(x) from 0 to 1. When I use Matlab's numerical integrator *integral*. It throws the following error:

```
>> integral(A1,0,1)

Error using integralCalc/finalInputChecks (line 526)
Output of the function must be the same size as the
input. If FUN is an array-valued integrand, set the
'ArrayValued' option to true.
```

Just to check if the integral isn't working how it is supposed to be, I defined a dummy function

```
f = @(x) sin(x)
```

I am able to integrate it properly. I am not sure what's the problem with the function A1(x). I am using Matlab R2018a

**Update:** I tried

```
w = @(x) 2
```

still didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read the error message...

Set `'ArrayValued'` to `true`

```
>> integral(A1,0,1,'ArrayValued',true)

ans =

   1.4575
```

Comment: My question it's a scalar function, why do I need to do this to make it work

Comment: Read the documentation. "For scalar-valued problems, the function y = fun(x) must accept a vector argument, x, and return a vector result, y. This generally means that fun must use array operators instead of matrix operators. For example, use .* (times) rather than * (mtimes). If you set the 'ArrayValued' option to true, then fun must accept a scalar and return an array of fixed size."